# Mariadb 10.5 FORCE INDEX can't be used with the PRIMARY key?

Tags: index, mariadb, mariadb-10.5

In a InnoDB table I can use any index with the FORCE INDEX or USE INDEX except for the PRIMARY one. (This is on RDS, if that matters)

```
ERROR 1176 (42000): Key 'id' doesn't exist in table 'mytable'
MariaDB [mydb]> select count(id) from mytable FORCE INDEX (`id`);
```

This is from show create table:

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `link_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  --
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `link_id` (`link_id`),
```

This does not work:

```
select count(id) from mytable FORCE INDEX (`id`);
```

This for example works: (and without FORCE analyze also shows that the same index is being used)

```
select count(id) from mytable FORCE INDEX (`link_id`);
```

There are other indexes in the table, and those also do not have problems.

Comment: Oh... After I wrote my question I realized `force index (primary)` does the trick, but I wonder why the count is almost twice as slower with primary key than with non unique additional key?

Comment: PRIMARY index is not separate index, it is clustered one. So its forcing makes no sense - if the optimizer uses non-optimal secondary index then specify IGNORE for this secondary index. And when you create primary key then the specified index name is always ignored and PRIMARY is assigned.

Comment: But the funny thing is that with the secondary index the query performs... faster!

Comment: *the funny thing is that with the secondary index the query performs... faster!* This is common.